# Cannot Create Sales Order using Dell Boomi

Tags: netsuite, boomi

I am trying to integrate Salesforce opportunity to netsuite sales order using dell boomi. I keep getting error **INVALID_TRANS_TYP** . I have given values to all mandatory fields in netsuite. ANy have any idea about what i am missing

Netsuite Response:

```
<Result>
  <id></id>
  <success>false</success>
  <errors>
    <error>
      <statusCode>INVALID_TRANS_TYP</statusCode>
      <message>Transaction type specified is incorrect.</message>
      <type>ERROR</type>
    </error>
  </errors>
</Result>
```

Answer (score 2):

While I'm not knowledgeable about Boomi (I use JitterBit because of the Boomi limitations), I can say that that is a standard NetSuite error.  What is Boomi sending to NetSuite?  Look in Setup > Integration > Web Servies Usage Log.  Find the action that corresponds with your attempt.  Then check the request file.  That is the actual request that NetSuite receives.

In my instances I see the following record type, and I've never had that error message come up.  If yours is not the same, that may be the issue.

```
<record xsi:type="tranSales:SalesOrder" externalId="0063800000kRhshAAC" xmlns:tranSales="urn:sales_2016_2.transactions.webservices.netsuite.com">
```

Hope that helps out some...

Answer (score 0):

I know you posted this years ago but for anybody else that stumbles upon this...

I would make sure you have the correct sales order Internal ID and not just the sales order number. This is a common mistake with Netsuite. If you go to the URL you can see the internal id at the end of the resource.